# An API with Tastypie for mobile devices

Tags: python, django, api, tastypie

I'm trying to make an API to be used with an android app.
I'm starting using Django + Tastypie, but i'm new in django technology. Looking for a secure scheme for API i've read this document http://django-tastypie.readthedocs.org/en/latest/authentication_authorization.html#apikeyauthentication. I think that's the best solution, because i can get a key for authorization and just allow authorized users to use my API.

The problem is that i couldn't find a good example on how to do it, i've read the documentation, but there isn't an example about how to use it, what and how should i send the user and password to the url?.

Comment: as I understand one should set corresponding header in request `Authorization: ApiKey daniel:204db7bcfafb2deb7506b89eb3b9b715b09905c8` can You specify Tour question. what does exactly confuse You?

Comment: I know how to use the apikey, but how can i get it??I know the url, but how should i send the user and password??

Comment: Do You need something Like refresh_token ? Or session Id. I think You should not mix Up password and API KEY

Comment: My requirement is, using the user and password, provide an api key to the user, is it possible with tastypie?

Comment: strange requirements... what is benefits of this solution comparing to obtaining session_id after login?

Comment: do you mean using the session_id like an api key???is it possible with tastypie?

Comment: You still need choose method to authentificate for session creation and then You can use http://django-tastypie.readthedocs.org/en/latest/authentication_authorization.html#sessionauthentication

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When using [api key auth](http://django-tastypie.readthedocs.org/en/latest/authentication_authorization.html#apikeyauthentication) you don't need to send the user's password, only the username and the api key.

To create an API KEY when user is logged in do like this (not actually tested):

```
      from django.contrib.auth.signals import user_logged_in
      from tastypie.models import ApiKey


      def generate_api_key(sender, user, request, **kwargs):
          api_key = ApiKey.objects.get_or_create(user=user)
          api_key.key = api_key.generate_key()
          api_key.save()

      user_logged_in.connect(generate_api_key)
```

Comment: But what should i send to get the api key???

Comment: You don't need to send, add tastypie to django admin, than you have a model for api keys. Click it and select the user (leave empty the key field) and it will generate an API KEY for the selected user

Comment: Is there any way to generate a dynamic api key with tastypie each time a user login??

Comment: use the logged_in signal https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/ref/contrib/auth/#django.contrib.auth.signals.user_logged_in along with create_api_key function http://django-tastypie.readthedocs.org/en/v0.9.11/authentication_authorization.html#apikeyauthentication

Comment: is there any example of that integrated plz???And, how should i send the user and password to get the api key??

Comment: Thanks, that's great, but...how should i validate the user and password of the user and how should i send it to the url??Again...thxs

Comment: this code runs after the user is validated.. you can do it in many ways, like html form or whatever you want. read about django auth https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/